How can I read the message from a queue after every 4 hours using camel routing
Below is the snippet of code am using to read the message from a queue using camel routing.
from("spring-rabbitmq:{{rabbitmq.in.exchange}}?exchangeType=topic&queues={{in.dummy.queue}}")
.process(dummyProcessor)
Now, I wanna read the messages at an interval of 4 hours. How can I do that?
I read about quartz component.
https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/quartz-component.html#:~:text=The%20Quartz%20component%20provides%20a%20Polling%20Consumer%20scheduler%20which%20allows,from(%22file%3Ainbox%3F
Updating code snippet that am using :
// This class extends RouteBuilder and configures a Quartz timer to trigger every two minutes.
public class DummyProcessorRoute extends RouteBuilder {
@Autowired
DummyQ3Processor dummyQ3Processor;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("quartz://myTimer?cron=0+*/2+*+*+*+?")
        .to("spring-rabbitmq:{{rabbitmq.in.exchange}}?exchangeType=topic&queues={{in.hd.dummy}}")
        .process(dummyQ3Processor);
}

}
@Service
public class dummyQ3Processor implements Processor  {
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange)  {
    
    String messageBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    exchange.getIn().setBody(messageBody);
    
    System.out.println("Message body:"+messageBody);
    
    

}

As far as I know, this only works with components that support scheduler (and spring-rabbitmq doesn't) so I don't think you can do it this way. If you could provide more info on what you are trying to solve, we can try to provide a solution for it.

@grekier I have one application which is processing the data and putting it into the queue of another application. Now other application should read the messages only at a scheduled time. That's my requirement. I am using rabbitmq and camel routing. Thank you for your response.

You can use quartz in camel as this provides a scheduled delivery of messages/task as you integrate.
below is the sample code for using quartz in camel:
from("quartz://cronJobNameDependsOnYou?cron=0 */4 * * * ?").toD("spring-rabbitmq:{{rabbitmq.in.exchange}}?exchangeType=topic&queues={{in.dummy.queue}}").process(dummyProcessor)

you can remove ? from cron if you want even you can add try catch statement to it to catch any exception code - after quartz use .doTry() and after process use .doCatch(Exception.class)
so basically what this quartz does is it provides a scheduled delivery of messages using the Quartz scheduler.
for more info you can visit its official documentation.
If you provide more code then probably I can help as I have integrated apache camel in my project.

I updated my question with the snippet of code I'm using. I'm trying to read the message from in.hd.dummy every 2 minutes . However, messages are not consumed.

from("quartz://myTimer?cron=0+/2++++?").routeId("Dummy Q3").process(dummyQ3Processor)    .split(body()).parallelProcessing().process(processDataHereFromExchange).process(ifYouWanToProcessMoreDoHereElseEnd).end();      probably this can help and instead of configuring cron time here just configure it in app.properties file and call it from there and append it like from("quartz://myTimer?cron=" + cronTime). hope so this will help

You should try to control the RabbitMQ route from another control queue, where you can use the quartz component:
Control Route
// This class extends RouteBuilder and configures a Quartz timer to trigger every two minutes.

public class DummyControlRoute extends RouteBuilder {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("quartz://myTimer?cron=0+*/2+*+*+*+?")
                        .to("controlbus:route?routeId=myRoute&action=start");
        }
}

The control route will start the Processing Route every two minutes.
Processing Route
public class DummyProcessorRoute extends RouteBuilder{
        @Autowired
        DummyQ3Processor dummyQ3Processor;

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("spring-rabbitmq:{{rabbitmq.in.exchange}}?exchangeType=topic&queues={{in.hd.dummy}}")
                        .routeId("myRoute")
                        .process(dummyQ3Processor)
                        .aggregate(new DummyAggregationStrategy()).constant(true)
                        .completionTimeout(500L)
                        .to("controlbus:language:simple");
        }
}

The Processing Route is processing the data from the RabbitMQ. We have to define a stop criteria, so we're creating a dummy AggregationStrategy. As soon as we have not seen any messages for 500ms (specified in the completionTimeout),
we will move on in the route. As we are throwing away all the exchanges in the AggregationStrategy and creating only one message with content to stop this route, it will send this exact content to the controlbus which will stop the route.
@Service public class dummyQ3Processor implements Processor {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange)  {
        
                String messageBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                exchange.getIn().setBody(messageBody);
                
                System.out.println("Message body:"+messageBody);
        
        }
}

public class DummyAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        return ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(getContext()).withBody("${camelContext.getRouteController().stopRoute('myRoute')}").build();
    }
}

